# mget in Bash script doesn't work due to huge files because of time out error

Tags: linux, bash, timeout, sftp, mget

I am trying to execute bash script which has mget `*.*` to download all the files in the directory. it is downloading couple of files in File1 but it is skipping the File2 part probably due to time out error. I believe it is due to time out error because

1) I tried to implement the same to other directories, it worked perfectly. Might be because the files in the File2 are less.

2)while i tried to do command line mode of

```
sftp username@hostname 
cd file2
mget *.*
```

it took at least 40 sec to  1 min to respond, but it did download all the files eventually.

So, I guess while executing the bash script, it might be stopping due to time out. Please suggest me the work around. Below is my bash script.

```
#test purpose only
#!/bin/bash
export Src_Dir=/path

File1=/path/*.*
File2=/path/Archive/*.*
DATE=`date +"%Y-%m-%d"`
Pass_Pwd='password'
PORT=22

cd "$Src_Dir" || { echo 'Failed to chdir into $Src_Dir' ; exit 0; }

/usr/bin/expect<<EOD


spawn /usr/bin/sftp -o Port=${PORT} username@host
expect "password:"
send "$Pass_Pwd\r"
expect "sftp>"
send "lcd ${Src_Dir}\r"
expect "sftp>"
send "mget ${File1}\r"
expect "sftp>"
send "mget ${File2}\r"
expect "sftp>"
send "bye\r"
EOD
echo "Download done"
```

Comment: Is it possible to use `scp` or `rsync` (over ssh) instead of `sftp`?

Comment: I have tried 

spawn scp -o Port=${PORT} username@host

but it says spawn id exp4 not open while executing

Comment: Why use expect with scp? You can just set up the copy mechanisms and use public/private keypair to authenticate eliminating the need for sending a password.

Comment: If you really want to use expect, you can change its timeout with `set timeout SECONDS`. The default is like 10 seconds.

Comment: @Shawn: That's exactly i did shawn, I have written 

 set timeout -1 above Spawn command, then it worked perfectly :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written `set timeout -1` above `Spawn` command, then it worked perfectly :)

Thank you guys :)

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to sftp/expect, and assuming you are not able to setup public/private key, consider using `lftp`. Much easier to script, and no need to deal with changing prompts, etc.

It can also support transfer of multiple files in parallel, which will speedup you data transfer. Look also at increasing the data transfer blocks (size, parallel) to make things more efficient.

```
lftp -u username,password -psftp://host:port/
```